# I'm trying to catch the rest of a class from a jquery element

Tags: jquery

I'm having a hard time trying to catch the `1` from `modal-id-`.

```
<div class="card-pg modal-id-1"></div>
```

How can I do that inside this function?

```
$('.card-pg').click(function () {

});
```

I tried using this

```
$(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/)
```

But that gives me a `classList` like `HTMLElement.classList` and if I choose `$(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/)[1]`, to catch the second class, I could lose the flexibility to insert `modal-id-1` class wherever I wanted to.

Comment: If the 1 is important, use a separate `data-` attribute to capture it. Parsing classes and ids is error-prone and a waste of cycles when you can just put the important data in its own field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with `.attr('class').split` to get a list of classes, then you can check each of them to check if it starts with `modal-id-`, *i.e.*:

```js
const MODAL_ID = 'modal-id';
$(function() {
  $('.card-pg').click(function() {
    let classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    classes.forEach(c => {
      if (c.indexOf(MODAL_ID) == 0) {
        let modal_id = c.substr(MODAL_ID.length);
        console.log(modal_id)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-pg modal-id-1">div</div>
```